# Output raw HTML in ejs templates with HtmlWebpackPlugin?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

In my `index.ejs` file, I have:

```
<div id="preact"><%- content %></div>
```

This should be outputting raw HTML. In my `webpack.config.js`, I have:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: path.resolve('./src/templates/index.ejs'),
  filename: path.resolve('./public/index.html'),
  templateParameters: {
    title: SITE_TITLE,
    baseUrl: BASE_URL,
    version: '0',
    content: '<h2>SSR Content</h2>',
    path: '',
  },
  inject: false,
}),
```

I expect it to output:

```
<div id="preact"><h2>SSR Content</h2></div>
```

But it's outputting:

```
<div id="preact">&lt;h2&gt;SSR Content&lt;/h2&gt;</div>
```

How can I get HtmlWebpackPlugin to output raw HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case is very misleading as under the hood *htmlWebpackPlugin* uses the implementation of lodash ejs templating engine. The thing is that the meaning of `<%=` and `<%-` are inverted between lodash's implementation and most of resources found on internet like the ejs implementation used for Ruby.

Thus with htmlWebpackPlugin :

> - `<%=` Outputs the unescaped value into the template
> - `<%-` Outputs the escaped value into the template

**Sources :** https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3689 and https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/751